# Remove 20 Spaces before and after buffer C

Tags: c, buffer, cell, padding

How do I remove 20 spaces from the beginning of a buffer and 20 at the end?

I can run a `for` loop starting at 20 and -20 at the end total but how do I copy each char by char to another buffer or is there a simple padding command?

Thanks for all the help so far now works but just displays a about 20 charactors i.e the MFI-40576-021 section from the dump it does now skip the 20 crap bytes at the start.

```
ReadFile(h,buffer,0x224,&read,NULL);
buffer[read] = '\0'; 
char newbuff[1000];
memcpy(newbuff,buffer+20,sizeof(buffer)-40);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new buffer of size s-40, do a memcpy from the source+20 to the destination for size s.

```
int read; //assumed
char buffer[0x224];
ReadFile(h,buffer,0x224,&read,NULL);

if(read-40 <=0) return;
char *newvar = (char*)malloc(read - 40 + 1);  // Fails with void to char error 
strncpy(newvar, buffer+20, read - 40); 
newvar[read-40] = '\0';
```

Comment: Casting the return value of `malloc` is unncessary.

Comment: @ryanbwork that's no excuse for omitting the terminating NUL character, exchanging dest and src, etc.

Comment: @ryanbwork also why are you thinking in C++ when the question is tagged "C"?

Comment: yes, I guess if he's going to be printing it as a string. I'll edit answer to include a \0.

Comment: @H2CO3 because I program in c++ for a living, and casting mallocs is a hard habit to get out of

Comment: I was hoping for a oneliner... :)

Comment: Not sure it's possible - to get that null character in you'll have to have at least two lines.. unless there's some magic I don't know about?

Comment: No joy with any scripts so far thanks for the all the answers. Posted update above

Comment: first, you can't use 'new' as an identifier for a variable, so change the name of your dest. second, strlen only works if your buffer has a null terminator at the end.

Comment: Yes, after looking at the ReadFile function, I think you could ensure that the there's a null at the end by using your read variable, but you may be overwriting good data too. Instead, just use read in place of strlen(string).

Comment: updated again still wont compile. I think after 3 days of being stuck here this project might have to join the bin.

Comment: I've edited my response, should compile now. Looks like you're using a c++ compiler, as Sean Bright mentioned you shouldn't get a compiler error without the malloc cast in c. I'd say familiarize yourself with basic string manipulation for a bit before trying anything more complex.

Comment: I am using visual studio it just crashes on that code with debug error i worked out a simplier method from your code which now skips the 20 bytes at start but only displays a few charactors I posted above again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "first, you can't use 'new' as an identifier for a variable," You're thinking C++ again. Sure one can in C.

Answer (score 0):

Use strncpy:

```
char *string = // however you obtain the string
char *new = malloc(strlen(string) - 40 + 1);
strncpy(new, string + 20, strlen(string) - 40);
```

Comment: In the `strncpy` call, I think you meant to write `string + 20` for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If altering the original buffer is acceptable, it may be easiest to use `memmove`:

```
char* string = /* insert code here to obtain the string */;
size_t len = strlen(string) - 40;  // Number of bytes to move
memmove(string, string + 20, len); // Move string down by 20 bytes
memset(&string[len], 0, 40);       // Clear out the remaining buffer
```

This general procedure will also work if the data in your buffer is not a string.  You'll just need to replace the `strlen` call with whatever code is needed to obtain the original buffer's length.